# Convert a list of list of words into vector NLP to feed into LSTM

Tags: python, lstm

I am working on an problem and currently have the dataset look like this:

[[["this is sentence 1"], ["I am sentence2, I am related to sentance1"], ["I am sentence3 and I am related to sentnce1 or 2 "]], [[...],......], [........], [......],.....]

with binary labels: whether the sentence1 of each instance tells the truth: yes/no

I have tried to extend all following sentence into the first sentence, performed tf-idf and trained via logistic regression, but the result was not good.

Now, I am considering using a sequential model LSTM to perform binary classification, LSTM requires 3 dimension input, my question is that how can I convert the current dataset into a valid 3d array and feed it into LSTM.

Any hint will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: To be added: each instance might have a different number of sentences, and each sentence has a different number of words